# dbcontext.savechanges always saves default Value

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure

I have a SQL-Azure database created with Entity Framework 6.1, Code-First.

The "datetime" field in my 'EmazeEvents' table was created like this:

```
datetime = c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()")
```

and defined like this in the code:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] 
[Index]
public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
```

I understand this means that in case this field is omitted in insertion, it will get by default the insertion date, which indeed it does.

However, I am having trouble inserting rows that set this field. Although I set the value of the appropriate variable, it still writes to the database the default date.

Some code extractions:
EmazeEvents is defined like this:

```
public class EmazeEvents:DbContext
    {
        public EmazeEvents()
            : base("EmazeEvent")
        { }

public DbSet<EmazeEvent> events { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I do is:

```
context = new EmazeEvents();
EmazeEvent e = new EmazeEvent();

// e.datetime does get the correct date
e.datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-05-31T00:00:06.8900000", "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

context.events.Add(e);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The record written to the database has the current date-time, ignoring the one in e.datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with the definition of the 'datetime' field. When I removed the:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

It started letting me write other values than the default.